# How can I implement a web connection with certificate in azure devops

Tags: azure-devops, azure-data-factory

In short, I need to delivery a ADF HTTP Linked Service certificate over Azure Devops. Coudn't find any article about it. Can you help me?

I have a Azure Data Factory with a HTTP Linked Service that use a client certificate. I found [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-http) it work fine:

```json
{
    "name": "ccee",
    "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/linkedservices",
    "properties": {
        "description": "Conexão ao CCEE.\n\nBase url estava https://servicos.ccee.org.br:442/",
        "annotations": [],
        "type": "HttpServer",
        "typeProperties": {
            "url": "https://servicos.ccee.org.br",
            "enableServerCertificateValidation": true,
            "authenticationType": "ClientCertificate",
            "password": {
                "type": "AzureKeyVaultSecret",
                "store": {
                    "referenceName": "KeyVault",
                    "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
                },
                "secretName": "my-site-certificate-password"
            },
            "embeddedCertData": {
                "type": "SecureString",
                "value": "**********"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now  I'm trying to deploy it using an Devops Pipeline but I was unable to transform the base64 cartificate "embeddedCertData" in a ARM parameter. There is no mentioning about the certificate code.

```json
{
            "name": "[concat(parameters('factoryName'), '/ccee')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/linkedServices",
            "apiVersion": "2018-06-01",
            "properties": {
                "description": "Conexão ao CCEE.\n\nBase url estava https://servicos.ccee.org.br:442/",
                "annotations": [],
                "type": "HttpServer",
                "typeProperties": {
                    "url": "[parameters('ccee_properties_typeProperties_url')]",
                    "enableServerCertificateValidation": true,
                    "authenticationType": "ClientCertificate"
                }
            },
            "dependsOn": [
                "[concat(variables('factoryId'), '/linkedServices/KeyVault')]"
            ]
        },
```

I even tried editing the ADF "ARM parameter configuration" adding embeddedCertData with no effect.

```json
    "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/linkedServices": {
        "*": {
            "properties": {
                "typeProperties": {
                    ...
                    "environmentUrl": "=",
                    "aadResourceId": "=",
                    "sasUri": "|:-sasUri:secureString",
                    "sasToken": "|",
                    "connectionString": "|:-connectionString:secureString",
                    "hostKeyFingerprint": "=",
                    "existingClusterId": "=",
                    "domain": "=",
                    "workspaceResourceId": "=",
                    "embeddedCertData": "|:-embeddedCertData:secureString"
                }
```

Comment: _I even tried editing the ADF "ARM parameter configuration" adding embeddedCertData with no effect._  Are you saying the template made no difference to the resulting ARM template in `adf_publish`? Does the connection give you the option of  getting the certificate from a keyvault?

Comment: Hi, I was looking for the template generated by azure devops in the CI process but in the adf_pubish there is no embeddedCertData tag as well.

Comment: I faced a similar problem. Adding a ARM parameter configuration should not be necessary. The parameters would be in file `ARMTemplateParameterForFactory.json` on branch `adf_publish`. Sometimes it works and the parameters of the Http Linked Service get properly added to the file on publish but sometimes after publishing the parameters are missing...

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in comments, I faced the same problem. However in my case sometimes it worked and the parameters of the HTTP Linked Service got properly added to the file `ARMTemplateParameterForFactory.json` on branch `adf_publish`. But after publishing again, the parameters got deleted even if I did no changes to the corresponding linked service.
After some investigations, which did not lead to a solution, I decided work around the problem by adding the following task to the YAML pipeline in Azure DevOps.

```yaml
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: Add HTTPLINKEDSERVICENAME parameters if not yet present (workaround as parameters sometimes get removed during ARM template creation)
  inputs:
    targetType: inline
    script: |
      $armTemplateForFactory = Get-Content $(sourceDataFactoryName)\ARMTemplateForFactory.json | ConvertFrom-Json
      $armTemplateParametersForFactory = Get-Content $(sourceDataFactoryName)\ARMTemplateParametersForFactory.json | ConvertFrom-Json
      $httpLinkedServiceResource = $armTemplateForFactory.resources |? { $_.name -eq "[concat(parameters('factoryName'), '/HTTPLINKEDSERVICENAME')]" }
      if (!$armTemplateForFactory.parameters.HTTPLINKEDSERVICENAME_password) { 
        $armTemplateForFactory.parameters | Add-Member -Name "HTTPLINKEDSERVICENAME_password" -value @{ type = "secureString"; metadata = "Secure string for 'password' of 'HTTPLINKEDSERVICENAME'" } -MemberType NoteProperty
        $httpLinkedServiceResource.properties.typeProperties | Add-Member -Name "password" -value @{ type = "SecureString"; value = "[parameters('HTTPLINKEDSERVICENAME_password')]" } -MemberType NoteProperty
        $armTemplateParametersForFactory.parameters | Add-Member -Name "HTTPLINKEDSERVICENAME_password" -value @{ value = "" } -MemberType NoteProperty
      }
      if (!$armTemplateForFactory.parameters.HTTPLINKEDSERVICENAME_embeddedCertData) {
        $armTemplateForFactory.parameters | Add-Member -Name "HTTPLINKEDSERVICENAME_embeddedCertData" -value @{ type = "secureString"; metadata = "Secure string for 'embeddedCertData' of 'HTTPLINKEDSERVICENAME'" } -MemberType NoteProperty
        $httpLinkedServiceResource.properties.typeProperties | Add-Member -Name "embeddedCertData" -value @{ type = "SecureString"; value = "[parameters('HTTPLINKEDSERVICENAME_embeddedCertData')]" } -MemberType NoteProperty
        $armTemplateParametersForFactory.parameters | Add-Member -Name "HTTPLINKEDSERVICENAME_embeddedCertData" -value @{ value = "" } -MemberType NoteProperty
      }
      $armTemplateForFactory | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 20 | Out-File $(sourceDataFactoryName)\ARMTemplateForFactory.json
      $armTemplateParametersForFactory | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 20 | Out-File $(sourceDataFactoryName)\ARMTemplateParametersForFactory.json
```

HTTPLINKEDSERVICENAME has to be replaced with the name of the HTTP linked service!

This task will add the missing parameters (in my case `password` and `embeddedCertData`) to the files `ARMTemplateForFactory.json` and `ARMTemplateParametersForFactory.json` if they do not yet exist.